# Concatenating folder names to file name and copy file to a folde

Tags: c#

My folder structure is as .. temp\2016\09\11\16

In the last folder I have multiple text/json files.

I would like to run a console application that would loop through every folder and rename the files with foldernames concatenated.

So a file abcd.json would become 2016091116_abcd.json

Then copy this file to another folder.

I tried..

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace concatdf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string folderPath = "D:\\500GBNP\\Projects\\temp";

            DirectoryInfo startDir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

            RecurseFileStructure recurseFileStructure = new RecurseFileStructure();
            recurseFileStructure.TraverseDirectory(startDir);
        }

        public class RecurseFileStructure
        {
            public void TraverseDirectory(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
            {
                var subdirectories = directoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories();

                foreach (var subdirectory in subdirectories)
                {
                    TraverseDirectory(subdirectory);
                }

                var files = directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles();

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    HandleFile(file);
                }
            }

            void HandleFile(FileInfo file)
            {
                string destfolderPath = "D:\\500GBNP\\Projects\\temp1\\";
               file.CopyTo(destfolderPath+file.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code I'm able to traverse and copy all files to target directory but file names do not get concatenated with foldernames.

So a file abcd.json in folder temp\2016\09\11\16 would become 2016091116_abcd.json and all files get copied to temp1 folder.

I would sincerely appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: `temp\2016\09\11\116\abcd.json` would not become `2016091116_abcd.json` with the code that you have shown.

Comment: Can you explain why the questions Peter linked do not answer your question?

Comment: @Llama no, it will not, it just copies the file to temp1 folder

Comment: So are you saying that you're trying to flatten the structure into a single directory, and you're concatenating any subfolder names in as part of the filename?

Comment: @Llama because the code does not have any info how to get linked directory names at HandleFile function to concatenate them to filename

Comment: Well, your question didn't ask for that. I appreciate that English isn't your native language, but this could be worked around by providing several examples.

Comment: @Llama y.. concatenating any subfolder names as part of the filename

Comment: hint: whenever you're combining paths, best use `Path.Combine`

Comment: .NET includes a recursive file enumeration capability, you don't need to write that. Are you just asking how to use `string.Split('\')` and `string.Join(...)` to create the concatenated file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the folder name in each recursion and append the destination filename.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace concatdf
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string folderPath = "D:\\500GBNP\\Projects\\temp";

        DirectoryInfo startDir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

        RecurseFileStructure recurseFileStructure = new RecurseFileStructure();
        recurseFileStructure.TraverseDirectory(startDir, string.Empty);
    }

    public class RecurseFileStructure
    {
        public void TraverseDirectory(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, string fileAppend)
        {
            var subdirectories = directoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories();

            foreach (var subdirectory in subdirectories)
            {
                TraverseDirectory(subdirectory, fileAppend + subdirectory.Name);
            }

            var files = directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                HandleFile(file, fileAppend);
            }
        }

        void HandleFile(FileInfo file, string fileAppend)
        {
            string destfolderPath = "D:\\500GBNP\\Projects\\temp1\\";
            file.CopyTo(destfolderPath + fileAppend +"_"+ file.Name);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that OP necessarily wants to name files in the base directory "_fileName".

Comment: hmmm, that's true

Comment: flename tends to become too big.. Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'D:\500GBNP\Projects\temp1\D:\500GBNP\Projects\swanvi\swanvienrichdata\swenrich\2016D:\500GBNP\Projects\swanvi\swanvienrichdata\swenrich\2016\09D:\500GBNP\Projects\swanvi\swanvienrichdata\swenrich\2016\09\10D:\500GBNP\Projects\swanvi\swanvienrichdata\swenrich\2016\09\10\06_0_e5809528a36842908158ebefdd78ce62_1.json'

Comment: Also at each iteration foldernames get repeated

Comment: We are just appending folder names, however it looks like it is printing the folder structure. Can you clarify?

'D:\500GBNP\Projects\temp1\D:\500GBNP\Projects\swanvi\swanvienrichdata\swenrich\2016D:\500GBNP\Projects\swanvi\swanvienrichdata\swenrich\2016\09D:\500GBNP\Projects\swanvi\swanvienrichdata\swenrich\2016\09\10D:\500GBNP\Projects\swanvi\swanvienrichdata\swenrich\2016\09\10\06_0_e5809528a36842908158ebefdd78ce62_1.json'

Comment: @Syed `fileAppend + subdirectory` -> `fileAppend + subdirectory.Name`

Comment: Ah! Thanks. That answers.

Comment: Use `Path.Combine` to combine folder and file names

Answer (score 1):

We just need to make HandleFile a bit more intelligent. Let's take the last 4 folder names and add it to the name..

```
void HandleFile(FileInfo file)
{
    string destfolderPath = "D:\\500GBNP\\Projects\\temp1\\";
    var pathBits = file.DirectoryName.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);
    var s = string.Concat(pathBits[^4..]);
    file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destfolderPath, s+'_'+file.Name));
}
```

This renames the file as it copies (which seemed a more sensible way to go, to me). If you truly want to rename the file before you copy, insert a call to FileInfo.MoveTo() after you copy

Strive to use Path when working with paths, not string concatenation

Comment: pathBits is a string[] which does not have Last extension method

Comment: It does if you `using System.Linq` because arrays are IEnumerable

Comment: now I get         error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Func<string, bool>' at  4

Comment: Now, it says cannot convert from System.Range to.. Do I need another using??

Comment: What's the full error? It works for me.. https://dotnetfiddle.net/zdSVA7

Comment: error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Range' to 'System.Func<string, bool>'

Comment: what version of c# are you on? If your version doesn't support this, you could alternatively `pathBits.Reverse().Take(4).Reverse()` or `pathBits.Skip(pathBits.Length-4)`

Comment: @Arnab Ranges are part of C# 8, I believe. Presumably you're using an older version of the language. You could change it to `pathBits.Skip(4)`, which is less efficient as far as I'm aware, but it will get the job done.

Comment: dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.201
 Commit:    a09bd5c86c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.4
  Commit:  f27d337295

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Comment: Skip works but any idea why Ranges do not.. I have .net5, do I need to install anything else..

Comment: My .csproj shows i'm on .net5.. <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: @Arnab That's the .NET version, not the C# language version. Though the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults) suggests C# 9 should be used as the default for .NET 5. Anyway, if you want to use a different C# version, that page should tell you how. You can scroll down for possible values.

Answer (score 1):

What about something simpler like this?:

```
public static void CopyFiles(DirectoryInfo sourceDirectory, DirectoryInfo targetDirectory)
{
    // This will provide all files in sourceDirectory and nested directories
    foreach (var file in sourceDirectory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        // work out what the relative path from sourceDirectory is
        // e.g. 2016\09\11\16\abcd.json
        string relativePath = Path.GetRelativePath(sourceDirectory.FullName, file.FullName);

        // get the directory part and replace the separator with an empty string (this could be
        // made more efficient)
        string directoryPart = Path.GetDirectoryName(relativePath)
                                   .Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), string.Empty);

        // get just the filename
        string filePart = Path.GetFileName(relativePath);

        // combine the target directory, the directory part, and the filename part
        // I've made the assumption that you don't want files in the base directory
        // to be called _filename, so we just use filePart when there is no directoryPart
        string newFileName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryPart) ? filePart : $"{directoryPart}_{filePart}";
        string newFullName = Path.Combine(targetDirectory.FullName, newFileName);

        // copy the file to the new location
        file.CopyTo(newFullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather see you use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` than `@"\"`.